# local host responds with deprecation warning

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, localhost

What im trying to accomplish seems quite strait forward. I want to pull my live version of wordpress onto my local machine and run it on localhost so I can play with themes and make edits in dreamweaver and such. I should make note that this is multisite wp just updated to the most recent version of 3.6.1

The issue I'm having is that even though localhost recognizes my root folder as being in the right location it will not open and run the site. I have gotten a slew of errors including "the requested URL/wp-signup.php was not found on this server" and the most recent is an odd one.

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and
>   will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lifefarout/www/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line
>   1142
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lifefarout/www/wp-includes/wp-db.php:1142)
>   in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lifefarout/www/wp-includes/ms-settings.php
>   on line 91

this is line #1142

```
$this->dbh = mysql_connect( $this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, $new_link, $client_flags );
```

this is line #91

```
header( 'Location: ' . $destination );
```

My machine: OSX 10.8.5, MAMP version 2.2 (both apache and Mysql are operating as they should)

What I have done so far: Used ftp to transfer www/ folder to the .htdocs folder on my local computer where MAMP in pointing. Backed up .sql database from server using phpmyadmin. Created a database on local phpmyadmin with same name as the one I exported. Imported database. created a user. Adjusted wp-config.php to read the following.

```
<?php
/**
 * The base configurations of the WordPress.
 *
 * This file has the following configurations: MySQL settings, Table Prefix,
 * Secret Keys, WordPress Language, and ABSPATH. You can find more information
 * by visiting {@link http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php Editing
 * wp-config.php} Codex page. You can get the MySQL settings from your web host.
 *
 * This file is used by the wp-config.php creation script during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can just copy this file
 * to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'lifefa5_lifefarout');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'null');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define('AUTH_KEY',         '.*>a;snGx`hMa6&2|X$3g/:k3k6FYF]Z|+K1[>vADAQ/KHt]S:0WBLq|T-m>1Co7');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'x+Xphn TxO|<h -M>o|sOG2iyic*}oWpf71jsd&|ma5x;b6Q,*47ZPgpPrZnb ]#');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'v?o{lCRqbMf)_rrq*c8z3Ey!*e>&d+Ee<K{aWUfnF@i%#j|A8rBv(9u7i@l ]-0t');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'PFj08]|>D[p?b+|Iz8%8-N>-#k+9>Li-1v<e;l2=-TOBnt&rRA-ZK/|Pk#v1r-h_');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'WEj#d~*= |!3uwI`~;@*+5I_WD7[4_0X_3=5Ev*zL^Cr+guSLu-U3(+HewIO:-QV');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', '_I(.y=F`$PUe}-d~||u%`E6DO!|H^r00EK>/T((M*F<-n0B|b5$^GjUAeokg:<gW');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'w(4G,N.#@a!>~Svw|h[|-AI`}?OyYxs3FT)O2:FydEWx?M@Pmm8u!ik.$fRov0|r');
define('NONCE_SALT',       '2<aWfduVE8Anry(E jTg+(*%cE{-z0p_<V .FOe}xW}8-@(5mTpU3%J5n:Xc]+Gr');

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each a unique
 * prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

/**
 * WordPress Localized Language, defaults to English.
 *
 * Change this to localize WordPress. A corresponding MO file for the chosen
 * language must be installed to wp-content/languages. For example, install
 * de_DE.mo to wp-content/languages and set WPLANG to 'de_DE' to enable German
 * language support.
 */
define('WPLANG', '');

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', 'true');

define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', 'true');

define('MULTISITE', 'true');
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', 'false');
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

I also edited my .htaccess to read the following:

```
# To set your custom php.ini, add the following line to this file:
# suphp_configpath /home/yourusername/path/to/php.ini

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lifefarout\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lifefarout\.com$
RewriteRule ^lifefarout\.co$ "http\:\/\/lifefarout\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lifefarout\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lifefarout\.com$
RewriteRule ^lfarout\.com$ "http\:\/\/lifefarout\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lifefarout\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lifefarout\.com$
RewriteRule ^lifefarout\.info$ "http\:\/\/lifefarout\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lifefarout\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lifefarout\.com$
RewriteRule ^lifefarout\.me$ "http\:\/\/lifefarout\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lifefarout\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lifefarout\.com$
RewriteRule ^lifefarout\.mobi$ "http\:\/\/lifefarout\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lifefarout\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lifefarout\.com$
RewriteRule ^lifefarout\.net$ "http\:\/\/lifefarout\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lifefarout\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lifefarout\.com$
RewriteRule ^lifefarout\.org$ "http\:\/\/lifefarout\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lifefarout\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lifefarout\.com$
RewriteRule ^mylfo\.mobi$ "http\:\/\/lifefarout\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lifefarout\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lifefarout\.com$
RewriteRule ^mylfo\.net$ "http\:\/\/lifefarout\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lifefarout\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lifefarout\.com$
RewriteRule ^mylifefarout\.com$ "http\:\/\/lifefarout\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lifefarout\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lifefarout\.com$
RewriteRule ^ourlfo\.com$ "http\:\/\/lifefarout\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lifefarout\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lifefarout\.com$
RewriteRule ^eventsfarout\.com$ "http\:\/\/lifefarout\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lifefarout\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lifefarout\.com$
RewriteRule ^livefarout\.com$ "http\:\/\/lifefarout\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lifefarout\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lifefarout\.com$
RewriteRule ^livingfarout\.com$ "http\:\/\/lifefarout\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lifefarout\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lifefarout\.com$
RewriteRule ^lifefarout\.us$ "http\:\/\/lifefarout\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lifefarout\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lifefarout\.com$
RewriteRule ^lifefarout\.com$ "http\:\/\/lifefarout\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lifefarout\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lifefarout\.com$
RewriteRule ^livelifefarout\.com$ "http\:\/\/lifefarout\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lifefarout\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lifefarout\.com$
RewriteRule ^lifeisfarout\.com$ "http\:\/\/lifefarout\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Im still quite new to stackoverflow and any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm very new to WP, so I'm sure there is something that I'm missing.

If you need more information or would like me to share additional files please let me know and I'll be happy to help you help me! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you open a simple PHP file in `http://localhost/test.php`? Does this work `http://localhost/phpMyAdmin/`? Do you really need those `lifefarout` rewrites?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using OSX (10.9), Mamp (Pro v2.2) - go to the 'server' tab and under 'PHP' change the version to 5.4.x - it will stop the debug warning messages.

You're using PHP 5.5.x (default on Mamp install) which is generating these warnings.

Answer (score 0):

The warning about mysql_connect() means that the version of PHP you are running, considers the "mysql" extension as being deprecated and suggests other extensions. So in a future PHP version, this version of Wordpress won't work, unless configured to use these other extensions (if that's possible).

However this warning is just a warning and is not related with the other error "not found".

Answer (score 0):

You can hide this message be turning off debugging mode of WordPress.

Change

```
define('WP_DEBUG', 'true');
```

to

```
define('WP_DEBUG', 'false');
```

Answer (score 0):

To change error warning in WordPress you can do the following with `WP_DEBUG` set to true.

1. In your `wp-content` folder create a new folder called `mu-plugins`
2. Create a php file in this folder with the error level you want to use.

For example:

```
 //turns off deprecated and strict errors
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT);
```

You can see the list here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php